# PineScript (Tradingview) - I would like to see a line (Horizontal Ray) just below the candle instead of triangles

Tags: css, pine-script

As in Title. I am trying to plot a horizontal radius below the body of the candle. At the moment when the triangles appear, I would like a horizontal ray pointing to the right.
Can anyone help me please? : d

Code:

```
//@version=4
study("attempt 1", overlay=true)

BarLow = low

BarHigh = high

BarOpen = open

BarClose = close

PreviousBarHigh = high[2]

PreviousBarLow = low[2]

PreviousBarOpen = open[2]

PreviousBarClose = close[2]


Drop = (BarHigh < PreviousBarOpen) and (BarOpen < PreviousBarOpen) and (BarClose < PreviousBarClose) and (PreviousBarLow > BarHigh)


Increase = (PreviousBarHigh < BarOpen) and (PreviousBarClose < BarOpen) and (PreviousBarHigh < BarLow)


plotshape(Increase, style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.green, size = size.tiny, offset=-2)

plotshape(Drop, style = shape.triangledown , location = location.abovebar, color = color.red, size = size.tiny, offset=-2)
```

Comment: can you be more specific, any image you can provide as eg.

Comment: Check `line.new()` function, it's doing exactly what you want